# django+gunicorn+nginx 404 serving static files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have django+gunicorn+nginx running on 192.168.1.81:3000. The web app will not serve any static files; it returns a 404 error. This suggests that there is a problem with the nginx virtual server config file. I have tried several solutions offered on stack overflow with no success. What is wrong with the nginx virtual server file?

```
upstream app_server {
        server unix:/home/pi/door_site/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.1.81;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        access_log /home/pi/door_site/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/pi/door_site/logs/nginx-error.log;
        location /static/ {
                alias /home/pi/door_site/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://app_server;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: yes I have set STATIC_ROOT and run `python manage.py collectstatic` to populate the directory that STATIC_ROOT points to

Comment: That is the tutorial I followed. I ran through it again to see if I missed anything regarding permissions and it all seems in order. Could it be that not removing the default nginx configuration file is causing the issue?

Comment: Have you checked your nginx log to see what path the `/static/` url actually tries to read?

Comment: both the access and error logs are empty

Answer (score 2):

In Nginx virtual server conf file inside **server** section you need to add to **location** sections for Nginx can serve files in /static/ and /media/ folders:

```
location /media {
    alias /path/to/your/folder/media;
}

location /static {
    alias /path/to/your/folder/static;
}
```

After that test Nginx configuration:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

and reload Nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

(or restart - `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` )

Comment: * add _two_ location sections - i'm mispelling, sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this config using server root and try_files

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/pi/door_site/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.81;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /home/pi/door_site/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/pi/door_site/logs/nginx-error.log;

    root /path/to/root # place your static directories in root i.e /path/to/root/static

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

This will try to find your static file and then move onto your app server.

Make sure nginx is running as the right user to access your files and that your static files permissions are correctly set perhaps with:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX static_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was a permission issue on static directory and it worked after assigning proper permissions.